# How to loop through parent directories in php?

Tags: php

There are all these resources for recursively looping through sub directories, but I haven't found ONE that shows how to do the opposite.

This is what I want to do...

```
<?php

// get the current working directory

// start a loop

    // check if a certain file exists in the current directory

    // if not, set current directory as parent directory

// end loop
```

So, in other words, I'm searching for a VERY specific file in the current directory, if it doesn't exist there, check it's parent, then it's parent, etc.

Everything I've tried just feels ugly to me. Hopefully someone has an elegant solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: "Everything I've tried just feels ugly to me." - why does it feel ugly? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Can't you check for `myfile`, then `../myfile`, `../../myfile` etc.?

Comment: What do you want to searching.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you've created so far.

Comment: @MikeW YES! Man I tried trimming off everything after the last slash. Exploding into an array, then poping items off the end, etc. It all felt wrong. This felt right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a recursive function like this

```
function getSomeFile($path) {
    if(file_exists($path) {
        return file_get_contents($path);
    }
    else {
        return getSomeFile("../" . $path);
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem with this method though is it doesn't know when it reached the root to stop. It just runs forever. And in my case locked up the computer. Lol

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be using ../ this will move you to the folder above. You can then get a file/folder list for that directory. Don't forget that if you check children of the directory above you then you're checking your siblings. If you just want to go straight up the tree then you can simply keep stepping up a directory until you hit root or as far as you are permitted to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$dir = '.';
while ($dir != '/'){
    if (file_exists($dir.'/'. $filename)) {
        echo 'found it!';
        break;
    } else {
        echo 'Changing directory' . "\n";
        $dir = chdir('..');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, so, in THEORY, I like this. Because `chdir()` returns TRUE or FALSE, not the new directory.

Comment: I also read you comment under the one you've marked as the correct answer, then you should probably change it?

Comment: I tried your example too, and it is broken. $dir will never equal '/' because `chdir()` returns a `BOOLEAN` value, not the directory name. Having said that, I think the recursive function is a more elegant solution. It's less code, reusable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Modified mavili 's code:

```
function findParentDirWithFile( $file = false ) {
    if ( empty($file) ) { return false; }

    $dir = '.';

    while ($dir != '/') {
        if (file_exists($dir.'/'. $file)) {
            echo 'found it!';
            return $dir . '/' . $file;
            break;
        } else {
            echo 'Changing directory' . "\n";
            chdir('..');
            $dir = getcwd();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some description or something to motivate this answer? I don't really get the value you're adding to the conversation.